# Что значит в Laravel- е request()->about?

Tags: php, laravel

Я не понимаю  что делает код `request()->about` в Լaravel-е .

Помогите разобраться с Helper функцией request();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
request()->about
```

Это алиас:

```
request()->input('about')
```

Что в свою очередь (для нагладности), = `$_POST['about'] / $_GET['about']`. (P.S. `request` работает одинаково для поста и гета). Офк он не в голом виде их получает а обрабатывает и фильтрует.

Так что-же делает? Да просто пытается получить внешние параметры, которые были переданы из формы(или гетом) под именем `about`.

Comment: где с вами можно связаться?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie скайп такой-же как и логин.